# GAE Blobstore Exception in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, spring, google-app-engine, jquery-mobile, blobstore

I am facing a very unusual issue when I am designing my `blobstore upload form JSP` page using  `jQuery Mobile 1.3.0`. I am posting the code below.

```
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService"%>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/common.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <%
   BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
 %>
 <form method="POST" action="<%=blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload")%>"
  id="uploadImageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="newsTitle">New Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="newsTitle" id="newsTitle" placeholder="Please enter some title" />
    <div style="clear: both; width: 100%;"></div>

    <label for="newsDescription">New Description</label>
    <textarea name="newsDescription" id="newsDescription" placeholder="Please enter some description" rows="10"></textarea>
    <div style="clear: both; width: 100%;"></div>

    <label for="newsPic">Choose Image (if any)</label>
    <input type="file" name="newsPic" id="newsPic" class="newsPic" />
    <div style="clear: both; width: 100%; height: 10px;"></div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" data-role="button" data-inline="true" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

I am getting this exception when I am trying to upload any file through this form to the blobstore.

```
WARNING: Error for /_ah/upload/agpsdW1paW5uZXdzchsLEhVfX0Jsb2JVcGxvYWRTZXNzaW9uX18YOAw
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:71)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.readTillFirstBoundary(MimeMultipart.java:245)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.parse(MimeMultipart.java:181)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.getCount(MimeMultipart.java:109)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.handleUpload(UploadBlobServlet.java:146)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.access$000(UploadBlobServlet.java:69)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet$1.run(UploadBlobServlet.java:112)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.doPost(UploadBlobServlet.java:109)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:110)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
```

When I am trying to upload using simple JSP page using normal css and jquery library everything works absolutely fine.

```
<%@ page
import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService"%>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>News App : Upload New News</title>

 <link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" type="text/css"
rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"
rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<%
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory
            .getBlobstoreService();
%>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div class="span10">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="/newpost">Post New Topic</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form method="POST"
                action="<%=blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload")%>"
                id="uploadImageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="text-info">Upload Form</legend>
                    <label for="newsTitle">News Title</label> <input type="text"
                        name="newsTitle" id="newsTitle" class="span12"
                        placeholder="Type some title..." />
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label for="newsDescription">News Description</label>
                    <textarea class="textarea span12" name="newsDescription"
                        id="newsDescription" placeholder="Type some description..."
                        style="height: 70px;"></textarea>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label for="newsPic">Choose Picture</label> <input type="file"
                        name="newsPic" id="newsPic" placeholder="Type some title..." />
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="span1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simply can't understand why this problem is occurring. I need your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is related to the fact that by default jQuery Mobile uses AJAX for submitting forms.

In order to be able to submit your forms without using AJAX you can disable it by adding the 
`data-ajax=”false”` data attribute to the `<form>` tag.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Based on the bottom of http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/forms/ this looks like it's a factor.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect Tolis has the answer on this, so I'll take a shot at the "I need your suggestions" part.

This is the kind of problem where it really helps to reduce the failure to the smallest possible test case (or at least a smaller test case than this). This helps in several ways: First, it'll often lead you to seeing the otherwise hard-to-spot typo that you might have made. (If I had a nickel for every time I accidentally typed "multipart/form-date"... But that's hard to spot when there's lots of extra clutter.)

Second, by eliminating distractions, it helps the people who are trying to help you by giving them less irrelevant stuff to wade through.

Third, if you do find a bug, a simple test case greatly improves the chance that it'll get fixed quickly.

In this particular case, I seriously doubt that either `spring` or `css` have *anything* to do with the behavior you're seeing. The non-file input fields could also go, unless they change the behavior you're seeing.